# (Insertion Sort) Java error: Cannot find symbol

Tags: java

I'm trying to revise my code for Insertion Sort. First I have 2 arrays: one int array for ages, and a string array to store names corresponding to the ages. I tried to sort the ages array with ascending order and it worked fine. When I declare the string array for names and try reordering it so that the names are still corresponding to the sorted ages, the code won't compile and has 1 Cannot find symbol error:

symbol:   variable names
location: variable sort of type InsertionSort

But it doesn't report an error for variable sort.ages and runs normally if I delete this line: `sort.names = new String[] {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"};`

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class newInsertionSort {
    int[] ages; //= {19, 20, 19, 80, 45, 5, 51};
    String[] names;

    void InsertionSort() {
        for (int i = 1; i < ages.length; i++) {
            int j = i;
            while (j>0 && ages[j] < ages[j - 1]) {
                int temp = ages[j];
                ages[j] = ages[j - 1];
                ages[j - 1] = temp;
                //add code to change the order of the names
                String temporary = names[j];
                names[j] = names [j-1];
                names [j-1] = temporary;
                j--;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ages));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(names));
    }
}

class newInsertionSortTest {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        InsertionSort sort = new InsertionSort();
        sort.ages = new int[] {19, 20, 19, 80, 45, 5, 51};
        //sort.names = new String[] {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"}; this line causes the error
        sort.InsertionSort();
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks to me that you have two implementations sort of on top of each other.  Maybe edit your code to just show the string sorting version.

Comment: You've got a *method* called `InsertionSort`, but you're trying to use it as if it's the name of a *type* here: `InsertionSort sort = new InsertionSort();`. That should be `newInsertionSort sort = new newInsertionSort();` - although both your type and method names are unconventional.

Comment: Your class is named `newInsertionSort` but you are trying to instantiate a class with the name `InsertionSort`. Either rename the class or change the instantiation to use `new newInsertionSort`.

Comment: Thank you all so much! I fixed the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared `InsertionSort sort = new InsertionSort();` this line.

Here you have not defined `InsertionSort` but tried to use it. So, the compiler is saying, I'm unable to find the variable with name `sort` of type `InsertionSort`.

Also, even if you remove line, `sort.names = new String[] {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"};`, I'm pretty sure it won't compile in its current form.

Working code will be like,

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class newInsertionSort {

    int[] ages; //= {19, 20, 19, 80, 45, 5, 51};
    String[] names;

    void InsertionSort() {
        for (int i = 1; i < ages.length; i++) {
            int j = i;
            while (j>0 && ages[j] < ages[j - 1]) {
                int temp = ages[j];
                ages[j] = ages[j - 1];
                ages[j - 1] = temp;
                //add code to change the order of the names
                String temporary = names[j];
                names[j] = names [j-1];
                names [j-1] = temporary;
                j--;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ages));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(names));
    }
}

class newInsertionSortTest {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        newInsertionSort sort = new newInsertionSort(); // Changed code here
        sort.ages = new int[] {19, 20, 19, 80, 45, 5, 51};
        sort.names = new String[] {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"};
        sort.InsertionSort();
    }
}
```

This will work.

Also, as a side note, Java uses camelcase for all declarations. like,

```
class ClassName {}
void methodName() {}
int variableName = 0;
```

Please try to follow these, so, when collaborating with more developers, you won't face any issues.

Answer (score 2):

You have taken your class name as newInsertionSort , but you are creating object of InsertionSort in  InsertionSort sort = new InsertionSort();

Just modify your object creation to-

```
NewInsertionSort sort = new NewInsertionSort();
```

It will work fine.

Also, in java class name starts with a capital letter.

Answer (score 2):

check your class name! it is 'newInsertionSort'; try to re-code with:

```
newInsertionSort sort = newInsertionSort();
```